# Dragging cells referencing to cells in different sheet with formula and skipping 40 rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have to reference

```
`Cell B2` in Sheet2 to Cell K7 in Sheet3  followed by
`Cell B3` in Sheet2 to Cell K47 in Sheet3 then
`Cell B4  in Sheet2 to Cell K87
```

basically skipping 40 rows in Sheet3.  But the problem is that the K column in Sheet3 contains a formula to calculate mean from J column cells within Sheet3.

There are over 200 cells in Sheet2 where I want to be able to drag cells to copy values from K cells in Sheet3 while skipping 40 rows.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
ExcelMind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B2 on sheet2:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!K$7,(ROW()-2)*40,0)
```

Then fill down

Comment: Works for me...  What did you see instead of what you expected?

Comment: It is just putting 0 in all the columns

Comment: Is it because I have MEAN formula in Column K? Because when I use your formula in a blank sheet it works fine :(

Comment: Shouldn't matter whether there are formulas or hard-coded values in ColK.  Maybe I'm  misunderstanding the direction of your references.  Do you want values from sheet3 to appear in sheet2, or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes I want values from Sheet3(K7,K47,..) to appear in Sheet2 (B2,b3,b4...)

Comment: Yes it works in a new workbook.. I just tried.. I am scratching my head now.. would it matter if my cells in Sheet2(B2,B3) are inside a table? Because they are inside a table

Comment: My mistake B2 is actually B7 in my actual sheet.. How do I change your formula now? .. it is B7,B8,... instead of B2,B3,...